# APC not changing its value in an AJAX context

Tags: php, ajax, apc

I'm encoutering a strange problem with APC and PHP. This is what I'm doing, and what is happening:

**index.php**

```
apc_store("test","test");
```

Files below are called with ajax, first `ajax_1` then `ajax_2`.

**ajax_1.php**

```
apc_delete("test");
apc_store("test","test2");
```

**ajax_2.php**

```
apc_fetch("test");
```

Result is:

> test

What's wrong?!

I also previously experienced troubles with APC user cache (it was emptying itself alone, I had no apc_delete in my code and no TTL defined)

PHP 5.3.6 with MAMP package (APC included)

---

I guess it's important to specify that I'm using PHP-FPM.. Does each FPM process has its own APC shared memory? It could explain a lot of stuff... Thanks by advance.